# We was or We were which is correct?

Tags: verbs, subject-verb-agreement

I several times, particularly,while reading novels, encountered the sentence ' we was ....' .But as per my knowledge is concerned were is appropriate verb instaed of was. Please explain it. Thank you

Usage examples:

From 
[The Life and Times of Ray Hicks: Keeper of the Jack Tales](https://books.google.it/books?id=tr05RO5PeWYC&pg=PA76&dq=%22we%20was%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix_5qL0c_eAhXJxYUKHfg0AA8Q6AEIQDAF#v=onepage&q=%22we%20was%22&f=false):

> ***We was hurryin'*** so as not to get caught in a blizzard storm. The northwest wind blowed over the mountain and was so strong ......The snow started a comin' down so fast, in short order we couldn't see where ***we was goin.*** ice was a freezin' on our faces. We turned to walk backwards, then forwards , ...

From [Tom Sawyer, Detective
By Mark Twain](https://books.google.it/books?id=1lDCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT23&dq=%22we%20was%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj81fPo0c_eAhUDyxoKHUe-BrA4ChDoAQg0MAM#v=onepage&q=%22we%20was%22&f=false):

> ***What we was after*** was a couple of noble big di'monds as big as hazel-nuts, which everybody was running to see. ***We was dressed up fine***, and ...

Comment: Usage examples need to be added to your question.

Answer (score 1):

*We was* is not standard English, it is used in some [regional dialects](http://www.bl.uk/learning/langlit/sounds/regional-voices/grammatical-variation/):

> The verb 'to be' has two simple past forms in Standard English - I/he/she/it was and you/we/they were. Apart from the special case of you, the distinction is, therefore, between singular was and plural were
>
> In some regional dialects, however, this pattern is not observed. ***In some parts of the country, speakers use was throughout, while speakers elsewhere use were exclusively.***  There are also dialects where the two different forms are used for the opposite function - singular were and plural was.

(BritishLibrary.uk)